# Building a custom Google Sign-In button in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-signin, google-plus-signin

I have two views in my html
1. Sign up
2 Sign in

I am using google google sign in button following this link:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button  with custom graphics heading

i am doing this in both the views sign in and sign up controllers,

```
    var googleUser = {};
  var startApp = function() {
    gapi.load('auth2', function(){
      // Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the client.
      auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
        // Request scopes in addition to 'profile' and 'email'
        //scope: 'additional_scope'
      });
      attachSignin(document.getElementById('customBtn'));
    });
  };

  function attachSignin(element) {
    console.log(element.id);
    auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
        function(googleUser) {
          document.getElementById('name').innerText = "Signed in: " +
              googleUser.getBasicProfile().getName();
        }, function(error) {
          alert(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
        });
  }
```

The issue is when i first goto sign up view when page loads, and then click on sign in link to come to signin page where i have same code for google sign in button
it doesnot work.